# Creating openlayers feature in the backend

Tags: node.js, maps, openlayers, geo, epsg

I have a website where I render a map using openlayers, I save the features (polygons) on the map to the database so I can load them later by doing this:

```
const format = new GeoJSON({ featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });
const json = format.writeFeature(feature);
const coordinatesToSave = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json).geometry.coordinates);
```

Which usually returns something like this:

```
  [
    [0.021913054136367526,-0.057815561863762355],
    [0.026207000014373007,-0.057815561863762355],
    [0.026207000014373007,-0.07047281626994106],
    [0.021913054136367526,-0.07047281626994106],
    [0.021913054136367526,-0.057815561863762355]
  ]
]
```

Now aslong as I create the features in the frontend, save them to the DB, then load them the next time this way:

```
const format = new GeoJSON({ featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });
const feature = format.readFeature(`{"type": "Feature","geometry": {  "type": "Polygon",  "coordinates": ${coordinates}},"properties": null}`);
```

It works fine, but what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

I have the map image with it's dimensions and extent, I need to generate the coordinates for a new feature from pixel coordinates of a polygon that I have,:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 (all in pixels)
```

Using the above I need to convert or generate coordinates which openplayers will be able to read, on the backend, so I don’t really have openlayers functions to use

Thanks

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getCoordinateFromPixel

Comment: I edited the post, sorry forgot to mention that I’m trying to do this on the backend without the openlayers library.

Comment: if you know the map size and extent you can interpolate coordinates for any pixel on the map `[ extent[0] + ((extent[2] - extent[0]) * pixel[0] / size[0], extent[3] - ((extent[3] - extent[1]) * pixel[1] / size[1] ]`

Comment: Using your equation, for an image with:
`extent: [0.00000000, -7324.00000000, 13607.00000000, 0.00000000]`
`height: 7324, width: 13607`
`polygon: {x: 408, y: 2973, height: 703, width: 473}`

I get this:
`[[408,-2973],[881,-2973],[881,-3676],[408,-3676],[408,-2973]]`

But what I don't understand is why openlayers method returns values like this:

`[0.021913054136367526,-0.057815561863762355]`

Are they normalized?

Comment: If you write with `featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'` the input is treated as EPSG:3857 coordinates but creates an EPSG:4326 GeoJSON

Comment: I see, now it’s alot clearer, thanks alot